# wordpress featured image (thumbnail) on header

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm working on making fixes to someones wordpress site, and i encountered this strange code in the loop.php and in a template file for a specific page. My goal is to change this to display the featured image in the header.I did some research into how to output the featured image using the get_thumbnail syntax, I don't normally do much in the back end / FTP of wordpress so thank you for your help and patience.

```
<?php 
/**
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage WP-Skeleton
*/
?>
</div>
<div id="primary">
<div id="content">
    **<?php the_post(); ?>
        <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(           get_the_ID('full') ), 'page-header' );
        $url = $thumb['0'];?>
        <div id="page-header" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $url; ?>');">**
        </div>
    <div style="clear"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="sixteen columns alpha">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h2 class="entry-title">Events</h2>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content ">
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> <!--  the Loop -->
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="event">
                  <div class="title">            
                     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title('<h3>', '</h3>'); ?></a>  <!--Post titles-->
                  </div>
                    <div class="event-img"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('event-img'); ?></a></div>
                    <?php the_content("Continue reading " . the_title('', '', false)); ?> <!--The Content-->
                </article>
                <?php endwhile; ?><!--  End the Loop -->
            </div>
        </section>
    <div>
</div>  <!-- End two-thirds column -->
</div><!-- End Content -->

</diV>
```

Comment: the page being displayed is http://merridees.jlbworks.net/events/

Comment: What is the issue? This all looks normal. The featured image (`get_post_thumbnail_id`) is being displayed as the background image for the element `#page-header`. The URL of this image is retrieved with `wp_get_attachment_image_src`. And `$thumb['0']` is the URL (altough the 0 should not use quotes).

Comment: thank you for helping me understand this a little better, currently this is the loop folder, the get_post_thumbnail is also in the full-width template code, and a custom template code that i assume was made to call a specific class of post. 'events'

Comment: I still don't know what you are looking for though. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the featured image inside the header, use the below code in it.

```
<?php
    if(have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            the_post_thumbnail();  
        endwhile;        
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: thank you for explaining that, but what if i wanted to display the featured image from the page not the individual posts.

Comment: the same code can be used inside the page.php to get the featured image of a page.

Comment: would I then need to get rid of the code inside the loop/template files?

Comment: no,you can display all the page/post attributes inside the loop.